# Finding library dependencies (make/cmake/linker)

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, mxe

I'm trying to build a cross-platform QT C++ application (Linux/Windows), using [MXE](http://mxe.cc) and cmake. I googled very, very hard, you don't know how brilliant my google queries were. Such queries. But:

**The problem: undefined references.**

```
/home/user/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.a(qregularexpression.o):qregularexpression.cpp:(.text+0x2b7): undefined reference to `pcre16_exec'
```

(and many others of this kind)

**The solution:**

```
cd ~/mxe && make pcre
```

then add to CMakeFiles.txt:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(pcre STATIC IMPORTED)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(pcre PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /home/user/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/libpcre16.a)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} pcre)
```

**Final problem: Other Undefined References.**

```
/home/user/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.a(qbytearray.o):qbytearray.cpp:(.text+0x60a): undefined reference to `uncompress'
/home/user/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.a(qbytearray.o):qbytearray.cpp:(.text+0x1a30): undefined reference to `compress2'
/home/user/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qharfbuzzng.o):qharfbuzzng.cpp:(.text+0x143e): undefined reference to `hb_font_funcs_set_glyph_v_origin_func'
```

But I don't know from what library this `compress` or `hb_font_funcs_set_glyph_v_origin_func` comes. I could google them one by one, but it looks like a stone age practice. And in a long perspective I don't want to do this for every cross-compiled project.

**The question(s):**

How do I find names of needed libraries, without reading qt build files? Is there a way to output dependencies (dynamic libraries needed) using cmake or make?

**Possible solutions:**

- I know I can use [ldd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120015/how-to-find-out-the-dynamic-libraries-executables-loads-when-run) on a binary file. What I need is something like link-time ldd. Is this possible?
- Maybe I could use make (during QT building stage) to print QT's dependencies. If so, how to do it?

**UPD: discovered**

- mxe related almost solution:

  `usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-pkg-config --list-all | sort`

  `usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-pkg-config Qt5Widgets --libs`

Comment: You don't need to do any of that. Use the cmake module provided by Qt: it will link your target with all necessary libraries that Qt itself depends on. This should be very simple - the work is already done, you only have to reuse it.

Comment: I have `find_package( Qt5Core REQUIRED )
find_package( Qt5Widgets REQUIRED )
find_package( Qt5Gui REQUIRED )
#find_package( Qt5Qml REQUIRED )` and `find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS  Core Widgets Gui Network)` and
`qt5_use_modules( ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}  Core Widgets Gui )`, but mxe's cmake should find them by default I guess - and it founds them, it can't find dependencies. (It builds ok in Linux if it can help)

Comment: I guess your main problem is that you are attempting a static build, thus you need the statically built version of some or all of the libraries Qt itself is using. pcre for the regular expressions, compress/uncompress from zlib, the hb_ function from Harfbuzz.
Maybe build a dynamically linked version once and then use ldd to find all dependencies?